# I want to find the number of unique badges a selected user has

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer

I want to find the number of unique badges a selected user has, i.e. 737 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

```
SELECT 
    Users.Id AS [Id], Users.DisplayName AS [Display Name], 
COUNT 
    (Badges.Id) AS [Number of Tag Badges] FROM Badges 
INNER JOIN 
    Tags ON Tags.TagName = Badges.Name 
INNER JOIN 
    Users On Users.Id = Badges.UserId
WHERE 
    Users.Displayname = 'Jon Skeet'
GROUP BY 
    Users.DisplayName, Users.Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing numbers that ought not be compared.

First off, the number on Jon Skeet's profile in that particular list is the number of *unique* badges he has. But a good number of the non-tag badges can be awarded multiple times, which means the unique count will not be the same as the total count. In reality, Jon has *thousands* of badges (over 10,000 in fact).

Secondly, you're using an inner join in your query there. That means you're only going to get badge results where there is actually a TagName set, which means you're only ever going to be selecting *tag badges* with that query (which I'd assume was your intention based on selecting the count as "Number of Tag Badges"). Jon Skeet does in fact have 668 tag badges at this moment. You're not seeing the regular badges he's earned because those would not have a TagName attached to them.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How would I find the number of unique badges (737) rather than just tag badges?

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating this. [This is enough](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761087/unique-badges):

```sql
select count(distinct concat(Name, Class))
  from Badges
 where UserID = ##userid:int##
```

`Name` is the badge name an `Class` is bronze, silver and gold. As someone can earn all classes of tag badge whilst the name is the same concatenating them together is enough.

I'd prefer to write the following in order to deal with the (unlikely) possibility of `python1` with a class of `2` and `python` with a class of `12` suddenly appearing but I can't get SEDE to accept it:

```sql
select count(*)
  from ( select distinct Name, Class
           from Badges
          where UserID = ##userid:int##
                )
```

Jon Skeet's 22656 on Stack Overflow (you can get this from the URL of his user page - https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

The query returns 737 for Jon Skeet. You may need to expand the returned row slightly as it's not showing the entire returned value.

You can call this directly via a URL as well: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761087/unique-badges?UserId=22656